# How can I force socket opened with python to close?

Tags: python, sockets, apache-kafka

I am currently using this lib to stress test a kafka server that I have set up: https://github.com/dsully/pykafka

```
import kafka
import time

def test_kafka_server(n=1):
    for i in range(0,n):
        producer = kafka.producer.Producer('test',host='10.137.8.192')
        message = kafka.message.Message(str(time.time()))
        producer.send(message)
        producer.disconnect()

def main():
    test_kafka_server(100000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What just ends up happening is that I end up overloading my own local machine.

I get **error 10055**, which according to google means that *"Windows has run out of TCP/IP socket buffers because too many connections are open at once."*  According to netstat, producer.disconnect() is not closing the socket, but rather putting it in a `TIME_WAIT` state.

The ipython debugger points to this line:

```
C:\Python27\lib\socket.pyc in meth(name, self, *args)
    222     proto = property(lambda self: self._sock.proto, doc="the socket protocol")
    223 
--> 224 def meth(name,self,*args):
    225     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
    226
```

as the culprit, but this then seems to get into messing with things at a lower level than I am comfortable with.

I had searched and found this [Python socket doesn't close connection properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040491/python-socket-doesnt-close-connection-properly) which recommended doing:

```
setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

so, I rebuilt the pykafka lib using that option in the io.py file:

```
  def connect(self):
    """ Connect to the Kafka server. """
    global socket
    self.socket = socket.socket()
    self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.socket.connect((self.host, self.port))
```

and I still get the same error.

Am I not putting the setsockopt line in the right spot?  Is there anything else I could be trying?

Comment: I don't see a way around it: http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are describing is normal TCP behavior at the socket level. When a user level program closes a socket the kernel does not free the socket right away. It enters TIME_WAIT state:

> TIME-WAIT  (either server or client) represents waiting for enough
>   time to pass to be sure the remote TCP received the acknowledgment of
>   its connection termination request. [According to RFC 793 a connection
>   can stay in TIME-WAIT for a maximum of four minutes known as a MSL
>   (maximum segment lifetime).

So the socket is closed. The socket.SO_REUSEADDR is for listeners (servers), doesn't effect client connections. Well, really used when binding the socket.